# T-SQL stored procedure - Detecting if a parameter is supplied as OUTPUT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, output-parameter

Consider the following T-SQL code snippet:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.SquareNum(@i INT OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i * @i
    --SELECT @i
END
GO

DECLARE @a INT = 3, @b INT = 5
EXEC dbo.SquareNum @a OUTPUT
EXEC dbo.SquareNum @b
SELECT @a AS ASQUARE, @b AS BSQUARE
GO
DROP PROC dbo.SquareNum
```

The result set is:

```
ASQUARE     BSQUARE
----------- -----------
9           5
```

As can be seen, `@b` is not squared, b/c it was not passed-in as output parameter (no `OUTPUT` qualifier when passing in the parameter).

I would like to know if there is a way I could check within stored procedure body (dbo.SquareNum body in this case) to see if a parameter has indeed been passed in as an `OUTPUT` parameter?

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: I agree with Giorgi - don't think you can check that at run time. If you are worried about enforcing it you might want to do this as a scalar function that returns the new value instead of using a procedure.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't have an answer, but out of curiosity, why would you want to do this? I wonder if there's an underlying problem that could be solved in another way.

Comment: @JoeFarrell Let's say you insert a row. But you don't normally need the new ID (or existing ID if already matched). But, when you provide an output parameter, you want that ID back. This way, the operation to resolve that ID can be shaved if not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a very simple way!

Make the parameter optional by setting a default value (@Qty AS Money = 0 Below)

Then, pass a value OTHER THAN THE DEFAULT when calling the procedure. Then immediately test the value and if it is other than the default value you know the variable has been passed.

`Create Procedure MyProcedure(@PN AS NVarchar(50), @Rev AS NVarchar(5), @Qty AS Money = 0 OUTPUT) AS BEGIN
DECLARE @QtyPassed AS Bit = 0
IF @Qty <> 0 SET @QtyPassed = 1`

Of course that means the variable cannot be used for anything other than OUTPUT unless you have a default value that you know will never be used as an INPUT value.

Comment: This allows you to detect if the parameter has been passed at all, but it does not allow you to detect if it was passed, but not as `OUTPUT` -- and that's exactly what the question was concerned about. The only saving grace is that, in cases where the parameter is *only* used for `OUTPUT` (i.e. it's not an in-out parameter) callers are likely to never fill in the value, allowing you to test for `NULL`. The question unfortunately concerns an in-out parameter (although that might just have been for illustration).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by query to sys views:

```
select 
    p.name as proc_name,
    par.name as parameter_name,
    par.is_output
from sys.procedures p
inner join sys.parameters par on par.object_id=p.object_id
where p.name = 'SquareNum'
```

or check in Management Studio in database tree:
[database] -> Programmability -> Stored Procedures -> [procedure] -> Parameters

Comment: I think the question is about how do detect whether the `OUTPUT` keyword was used in the code calling the stored procedure, not about the stored procedure definition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I don't believe it's possible. OUTPUT is part of the stored procedure definition so you should know when a parameter is or not OUTPUT. There is no way to set it dynamically so I think it's pointless to determine by code when a parameter is output or not because you already know it.

If you are trying to write a dynamic code, Piotr Lasota's answer should drive you to the correct way to realize when a parameter is Output.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query to get the name of all the parameters and to check if it is a output parameter:

```
select name, is_output from sys.parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   ------ THIS WILL GIVE YOU THE BOTH VALUE IN squared------

    CREATE PROC dbo.SquareNum(@i INT OUTPUT)
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET @i = @i * @i
        --SELECT @i
    END
    GO

    DECLARE @a INT = 3, @b INT = 5
    EXEC dbo.SquareNum @a OUTPUT
    EXEC dbo.SquareNum @b OUTPUT
    SELECT @a AS ASQUARE, @b AS BSQUARE
    GO
    DROP PROC dbo.SquareNum


  -----TO CHECK STORED PROCEDURE BODY-----

    SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), 
           OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)
    FROM  sys.procedures
    WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) =(SP_NAME)
```

Comment: This is not answering the question

Answer (score 0):

You can force the query to use the global variable [@@PROCID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/procid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) when calling the procedure, then check in the text if at least there is a "`OUT`" in the query after calling the procedure

It won't check if the parameter is using the `OUTPUT` statement, only if in the text of the query it has that word, only to "**remember**" who is writing the new code

**Weak-point**: By using this you can't call the procedure in a query without being in another procedure or trigger

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC TEST (@I INT OUT, @PROCID INT) AS BEGIN
    
        --Get the code that is calling this procedure
    
    DECLARE @Q VARCHAR(MAX)=(
        SELECT
            OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID)
        FROM SYS.ALL_OBJECTS
        WHERE OBJECT_ID = @PROCID)

        --Check if exists any code, if is null it means the user called in a query and testing

    IF @Q IS NULL
        THROW 50000, 'When calling procedure "TEST" you must specify parameter @PROCID = @@PROCID and call the procedure through another procedure or trigger', 1

        --Check if has the OUT word after the name of the procedure

    IF @Q NOT LIKE '%TEST%OUT%'
        THROW 50000, 'When calling procedure "TEST" the parameter "@I" must have the OUTPUT statement', 1

    PRINT 'code of the procedure here....'
END
```

Examples when calling it:

```
EXEC TEST 10, null      --> Null shows FIRST message
EXEC TEST 10, 10        --> Random number shows FIRST message
EXEC TEST 10, @@PROCID  --> Right command but not in a procedure shows FIRST message
```

Testing with another procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC TEST_2 AS BEGIN
    
    EXEC TEST 10, @@PROCID  --> Right command AND inside a procedure shows SECOND message
END
GO
EXEC TEST_2
```

The right way:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC TEST_2 AS BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @I INT = 10
    EXEC TEST @I OUT, @@PROCID  --> Now the code executes...
END
GO
EXEC TEST_2
```

How someone could avoid using the OUT:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC TEST_2 AS BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @I INT = 10
    EXEC TEST @I, @@PROCID
    --OUT --> Sadly, this way works too, because the word OUT exists and it is after the name of the procedure
END
GO
EXEC TEST_2
```